# Using a mapview with any pictures?

Tags: android, google-maps, customization, image

I need to use features of a MapView (like POI) on any image? 
is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing locations of the POI's along with information in a file. Then, create canvas from the initial image and 'plot' the points stored in the file on the new canvas with another image (E.g. a pin image).

File

```
{ poi: {
      "name": "Boots",
      "caption": "Pharmacy",
      "map_coord": {
          "x": 554,
          "y": 266
       }
    }
}
```

Canvas from image:

```
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(initial_image);
```

For each map coordinate:

```
imageCanvas.drawBitmap(pin_image, map_coord.x, map_coord.y, null);
```

Comment: I don't understand.
How can I replace the known picture in order with my picture, for example a dog or cat photo ?
I need to have the same behavior with overlays etc ...